# How to make an element within the list of another list of an object null?

Tags: algorithm, kotlin, sorting, data-structures

the goal is to remove all instances of "jim" from the array

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {    
var listOfObjects = arrayOf<Vehicle>(Vehicle("blue",2, Load(listOf("jim","jack"))), 
Vehicle("black",3,  Load(listOf("jim","jack", "johnny"))))
}

data class Vehicle(val color: String,val seats:Int, val load : Load)
data class Load(val people: List<String>)
```

Comment: First, `listOf` returns a list that cannot be changed, and unless you have `String?`, you could not set an element to null anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {    
  var listOfObjects = arrayOf<Vehicle>(
      Vehicle("blue", 2, Load(listOf("jim", "jack"))), 
      Vehicle("black", 3, Load(listOf("jim", "jack", "johnny"))))

  for (i in 0 until listOfObjects.size) {
    listOfObjects[i] = withoutJim(listOfObjects[i])
  } 
}

fun withoutJim(original: Vehicle) = 
   Vehicle(
       original.color, 
       original.seats, 
       Load(original.load.people.filter { it != "jim" }))
```

Playground link: https://pl.kotl.in/EQ3se_87D